# WPF: Editable ComboBox; how to make search/auto-fill functionality case sensitive?

Tags: wpf, user-experience, autofill, data-entry

Say I have a `ComboBox`, like so:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Height="30">
    <ComboBoxItem>robot</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Robot</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

If a user comes along and starts by typing a lower-case **r** into that `ComboBox` when it is empty, the `ComboBox` predictably auto-fills itself with the word **robot**. Great.

Now the same user comes along and starts typing an upper-case **R** into that `ComboBox` when it is again empty. Unpredictable, the `ComboBox` auto-fills itself with the lower-case word **robot**. Not great. I desperately want it to auto-fill itself with **Robot**, but WPF does not seem to want to smile down upon me.

No matter what you do (CAPS lock, shift+key), the `ComboBox` will always auto-fill with the lower case **robot**, provided that the lower case **robot** precedes the upper case **Robot** in the `ComboBox's` items collection.

Is there any way to prevent this? This behavior is maddening and makes for an absolutely abysmal user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .Net 4 you can set IsTextSearchCaseSensitive=True on the ComboBox (or indeed any ItemsControl)

Comment: Ha! I never knew this property existed... Thanks!